# Exercise 1.47 of Robert Megginson's "AnIntroduction to Banach space theory"

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

This is problem $1.47$ from Robert Megginson's An Introduction to Banach Space theory.

Let $X$ be any normed linear space and $f$ be an unbounded linear functional on $X$. Show that if $U$ is any open set then $f(U)=\mathbb{F}$.

I really don't have an idea about this. What I know is that $f$ maps open set to open sets. Also since $f$ is unbounded $\ker(f)$ is dense in $X$. But I don't know whether it plays a role here.

Any help will really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly $U$ contains a set $B_r(a)$, an open ball of radius $r$ with centre $a$. Then $f(U)$ contains $f(a)+f(B_r(0))$ so it suffices to
prove that $f(B_R(0))=\Bbb F$. Now $f(B_R(0))$ is unbounded, as $f$ is unbounded, also if it contains $x\in\Bbb F$ it contains all $y\in \Bbb F$
with $|y|\le |x|$. So $f(B_R(0))=\Bbb F$.